# How to create a custom remove row button in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, row

I have a button says remove selected button. On selecting a particular row or multiple rows I want delete it from the jqGrid. How can I achieve this? Can I use delGridRow method?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [delRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method to remove data from the grid, although you will need to send a request to the server if you also want to delete the data from your back-end.

Comment: thanks! i just need to delete it in client side ...its more like a shopping cart from where you remove the items added wrongly from client side only...